# Is numpy array multiplication always upcast to 64-bit?

Tags: python, numpy, scipy

When numpy arrays are multipled, is it always upcast to 64-bit?

Is it the same for scipy sparse matrix multiplication too?

If so, is there a generic method to force multiplication to 32-bit (dtype=numpy.float32) on a 64-bit OS?

This from a Windows 32-bit box:

```
>>> import numpy
>>> from scipy import sparse

>>> row = numpy.array([0,0,1,2,2,2], dtype=numpy.int32)
>>> col = numpy.array([0,2,2,0,1,2], dtype=numpy.int32)
>>> data = numpy.array([1,2,3,4,5,6], dtype=numpy.int32)

>>> A = sparse.csr_matrix((data,(row,col)), shape=(3,3), dtype=numpy.int32)
>>> x = numpy.array([8.0, 4.0, 2.0], dtype=numpy.float32)
>>> b = A * x.T

>>> b
array([ 12.,   6.,  64.])

>>> type(b)
<type 'numpy.ndarray'>

>>> for i in xrange(3): print type(b[i])
<type 'numpy.float64'>
<type 'numpy.float64'>
<type 'numpy.float64'>
```

Comment: please post an example of a multiplication where input of which is 32bit and output is 64

Comment: @shx2 example posted in question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your best bet for getting the `dtype` you want is making sure boths array involved in the multiplication are of the exact same `dtype` (=float32) to begin with:

```
A = sparse.csr_matrix((data,(row,col)), shape=(3,3), dtype=numpy.float32)
x = numpy.array([8.0, 4.0, 2.0], dtype=numpy.float32)
(A * x.T).dtype
=> dtype('float32')
```

Comment: Works on 32-bit and 64-bit OS's. A strange upcasting rule as you'd expect it to upcast to the highest data type between A and x rather than select the OS size. Thank-you - brill!